# jspm cannot find globalResources of a 'feature' plugin for Aurelia app

Tags: javascript, aurelia, jspm

Aurelia docs describe how setup and use a feature plugin at http://aurelia.io/docs.html#features

I'm having some trouble because it seems that jspm or Aurelia is transforming paths to resources.  I discovered that if I specify a current path with `.aurelia.use.feature('./plugins/auth');` that `calvert-auth/index.js` cannot be found when booting.  The request looks correct, but the browser throws a 404 error.  I fixed that simply by removing the "./" from `.aurelia.use.feature('plugins/auth');`

Next, I added a call in index.s's configure() to frameworkConfig.globalResources('auth').  This causes a new 404 error because the request is for calvert-auth/auth.html instead of the expected calvert-auth/auth.js

I suspect the problem may be in the jspm config or maybe corejs, but haven't been able to isolate it yet.

How do I create and use internal feature plugins for Aurelia?  Here are the classes:

config.js

```
...
paths: {
  "*": "dist/*",
  "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
  "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
},
...
```

main.js

```
import 'bootstrap';
import authConfig from './auth-config';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('plugins/calvert-auth', (baseConfig) => {
      baseConfig.configure(authConfig);
    });

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

plugins/calvert-auth/auth.js

```
export class Auth {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Auth: constructor()');
  }
}
```

plugins/calvert-auth/index.js

```
import {BaseConfig} from './baseConfig';

export function configure(frameworkConfig, configCallback) {
  frameworkConfig.globalResources('./auth');

  let baseConfig = frameworkConfig.container.get(BaseConfig);
  if (configCallback !== undefined && typeof(configCallback) === 'function') {
    configCallback(baseConfig);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Assuming your code above, and this structure:

```
main.js
plugins/calvert-auth/index.js
plugins/calvert-auth/auth.js
```

In main.js:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import authConfig from './auth-config';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('plugins/calvert-auth', (baseConfig) => {
      baseConfig.configure(authConfig);
    });

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

In plugins/calvert-auth/index.js:

```
export function configure(frameworkConfig, configCallback) {
  // this assumes you're importing a view model
  frameworkConfig.globalResources('auth');
}
```

In plugins/calvert-auth/auth.js:

```
import {noView} from 'aurelia-framework';
@noView
export class Auth {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Auth: constructor()');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @shanonvl, I've added more details to include my main.js.  Yes, the directory structure is the same.  The only difference I noticed was that I had globalResources('./auth') and yours shows globalResources('auth').  I tried that and the result is the same.  The request error is: Unhandled promise rejection Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/dist/plugins/calvert-auth/auth.html

Comment: Can you post the `paths` portion of your config.js ?  Also - and not sure that this will make a difference - the main.js should be:   
    ....
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('plugins/calvert-auth', (baseConfig) => {
    ....
( don't redo the aurelia.use )

Comment: Added snippet from config.js and corrected the aurelia.use chain.  Issue persists.

Comment: Updated my code above.  Apparently globalResources assumes that you're importing a view model, thus the auth.html request.   You can use the @noView decorator to tell it there's no view.